# Laravel 5 | Multiple Seeders in DatabaseSeeder.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've created a few custom seeders and now i'm trying to get them to seed from `DatabaseSeeder.php` but it will only do one at a time

#### Current DatabaseSeeder.php

```
    <?php  
use Database\seeds\CandySeeder;
use Database\seeds\ChocolateSeeder;
use Database\seeds\AlmondSeeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        $this->call ('FirewallModelsSeeder');
    }    

}
```

#### Here's I tried to run

```
public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        $this->call ('CandySeeder', 'ChocolateSeeder', 'AlmondSeeder');
    }
```

and

```
public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        $this->call arrary ('CandySeeder', 'ChocolateSeeder', 'AlmondSeeder');
    }
```

Only CandySeeder runs =/ - I have to move the one i want to be ran to the first in line. Is there a way to pass a list so they can all run. I tried having 1 line for each, but db:seed gave me an error that it couldn't redeclare seeder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();
        $seeders = array ('CandySeeder', 'ChocolateSeeder', 'AlmondSeeder');

        foreach ($seeders as $seeder)
        { 
           $this->call($seeder);
        }
    }
```

simply run the call function inside a loop

Comment: foreach ($seeders as $seeder) not foreach ($seeders $as $seeder)

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 5.1 :

```
Model::unguard();
$this->call(UsersAdminSeeder::class);
$this->call(TipoUsuarioTableSeeder::class);
Model::reguard();
```

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 8:

```
$this->call([UsersSeeder::class,RolesSeeder:class]);
```